# getting malformed policy error from cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, pre-signed-url

I am trying create signed urls for cloudfront. i followed the docs from amazon and was able to configure the cloudfront and s3 using console. but the problem is when i create the signed url(i generated the policy and signature using the linux commands) and prepared the below url
http://1q2w3e4r5t6y7u.cloudfront.net/4/myimage.jpg?Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kbHIyamJoZGdobTE4LmNsb3VkZnJvbnQubmV0LzQvM2IwYWNiMjYtYTUyOC00MTYwLWE1Y2YtNDEzZWI3NGRkNjcxLmpwZyIsIkNvbmRpdGlvbiI6eyJEYXRlTGVzc1RoYW4iOnsiQVdTOkVwb2NoVGltZSI6MTQwODczOTQwMH0sfX1dfQ0K&Signature=jOv/hpQSO7ChSYQ3w9k2EVh7MUrBxQ2dqbjQNPuEFcWgCKcBT6BufQoMnGWmVLHnIvFr8/ErQC2Q6iAxTyxHoHN7K9FMB2QmLbqaenKaRh8RIcufTmOlsbWXxMpQTwFOquQX7JE/2i4m6OGZBi4Chwse9fQwzHdQ4A6FPr/r8l0rDHLBXF58z8mq3tqJIqiE3joxJoy2K5dY4tzIXWCGZ25L941O8dkpSrmDbmQii8iGiJUGE0bFICpndlEbDVDUkHZsMSPXYt8fjJ2YTIbL58QtaVLMJeXY0kuDq4IUZ8ryp7BZ1Cqj5RKnkToIO4Qe5fNbfl9g-6nydcUbr6q72g__&Key-Pair-Id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

But i keep on getting "Malformed url" error. please help!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, it does look malformed... the signature has several `/` characters, and it shouldn't.

The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-linux-openssl.html) indicate that this pipeline can be used to build the signature:

```
cat policy | openssl sha1 -sign private-key.pem | openssl base64 | tr '+=/' '-_~'
```

If you do that, there shouldn't be any `/` left in your signature -- they would all have been converted to the `~` character.

Comment: Thanks Michael!! I just tested with the above commands and it worked. Now i have to figure out how can i do it programmatically!!